# I would like to modify the spbasic.bst file

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, apa-style

In my manuscript, I would like to use `socpsych.bst` for my output references but I could not find this .bst file on the internet. Instead I would like to use `spbasic.bst` in order to make it look like the one generated by `socpsych.bst`. For example, in the output references, I would like to get the journal names and volume number in italic. Any suggestion on how I can modify the `spbasic.bst` would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy answer on how to modify `bst` files.  The language of BibTeX is its own stack-based language.  However, there are a few good resources to guide you

Tame the Beast, by Nicholas Markey

http://tug.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf

and several papers by Oren Patashnik, the author of BibTeX:

http://bibtexml.sourceforge.net/btxdoc.pdf

https://www.pctex.com/files/managed/a/a3/btxhak.pdf

https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb24-1/patashnik.pdf

Other BibTeX resources:

http://www.bibtex.org/Format/

https://www.openoffice.org/bibliographic/bibtex-format.pdf