# Suppress contents of 'title' field of all entry types with unsrt

Tags: bibtex

I would like to suppress the printing of the contents of the `title` field in the bibliography; I use BibTex and the `unsrt` bibliography style. Is there any way to do so?
My example is as follows:

**bib.bib:**

```
  @article{13TaGyToTa,
  author  = {Tasi, G. and Gyevi-Nagy, L. and T\'obi\'as, R. and Tasi, T. S.},
  title   = {Vector algebra and molecular symmetry: A
             tribute to {Professor Josiah Willard Gibbs}},
  journal  = {J. Math. Chem.},
  volume   = {51},
  pages    = {2187--2195},
  year     = {2013}}
```

**main.tex:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\author{Author}
\title{Title}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Ez egy jo cikk. \cite{13TaGyToTa}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: simply empty title content: `title = {}`

Comment: @C.F.G - Is this meant as a joke? Having to edit the `title` field of lots and lots of entries in order to achieve a certain output format would seem to defeat one of the main purposes of the BibTeX approach.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that the OP document is an article so its bibliography should be few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unsrt` bibliography style -- along with many (most? virtually all?) other bibliography styles -- features a function called `format.title`. The `format.title` function is invoked by the BibTeX functions that format all entry types. The purpose of the `format.title` function is, you guessed it, to format the appearance of the contents of an entry's `title` field.

In the case of the `unsrt` bib style, the function `format.title` begins on line 233 of the bst file and looks like this:

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title "t" change.case$ }
  if$
}
```

To *suppress* the printing of the contents of the `title` fields of all entries, it suffices to change this function to

```
FUNCTION {format.title}

{ "" }
```

so that all it does is to return an empty string.
I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `unsrt.bst` in your TeX distribution and make a copy of it. Name the copy, say, `unsrt-notitles.bst` and save it in the directory where your main tex file is located.
- Open the file `unsrt-notitles.bst` in a text editor and go to line 233. Change the function `format.title` as discussed above.
- Save the file `unsrt-notitles.bst`.
- In your main file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` to \bibliographystyle{unsrt-notitles}` and perform a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.
  Happy BibTeXing!

Comment: Just a guidance: where can I read and learn about language of `.bst` files? Is that `JavaScript`?

Comment: @C.F.G - A good starting point is Nicholas Markey's essay, [Tame the Bst](http://tug.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf). For additional pointers, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/487727/5001) by [Steven Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/25858/steven-b-segletes).

Comment: ++1. Thanks a lot.